# Idiomatic asynchronous design

Tags: python, asynchronous

Are there any sorts of useful idioms I can make use of when writing an API that is asynchronous? I would like to standardize on something as I seem to be using a few different styles throughout. It seems hard to make asynchronous code simple; I suppose this is because asynchronous operations are anything but.

At the most basic level, the user of the API must be able to:

1. Have data pushed to them as it becomes available

   Check the status of the asynchronous operation

   Be notified of errors that occur

   Wait for completion (converting the asynchronous operation to a synchronous one)

My classes support several asynchronous operations. I have been putting some of the status/error callbacks in the class around it, but the class is becoming gunked up with a lot of incidental fields, as well as getting too large. I am curious if anyone has used an asynchronous API they found to be well-organized. I have looked at .NET's Begin/EndAsyncOperation + AsyncResult design, as well as some classes in Java (e.g. Future).

This is being written in Python, so it remains very flexible. There is a caveat: some of these asynchronous operations are being marshaled to a remote machine and executed over there. Thus, not every operation necessarily executes in a separate thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also have a look at the Asynchronous Completion Token and ActiveObject patterns.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look at [Python Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/). It is a nice [Reactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern) based API that supports [asynchronous](http://twistedmatrix.com/projects/core/documentation/howto/async.html) operations. [Proactor](http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/no/proactor.pdf) is the common term for asynchronous completion handler like frameworks.

Comment: I have looked at Twisted some. It looks nice, but I don't think it would help me in structuring asynchronous operations that take place on the local machine.

Comment: @Matt sure it does.  Not everything has to be network related.  Understanding twisted's reactor pattern implementation will definitely help you, though.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the **Observer** design pattern.  [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Your client object is an **Observer**.  Your API belongs to an object that's **Observable**.

Each client (in Java parlance) implements the **Observer** interface.  In Python, it's a matter of each client offering a number of methods that your observable will use.

```
class SomeClientInterface( object ):
    def update( self, source, data ):
        # handle data being pushed from Observable source
    def error( self, from, status ):
        # handle error in Observable source
```

Your Observable object has a way for Observers to register and do other things.

```
class Observable( object ):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.clients= set()
    def register( self, observer ):
        self.clients.add( observer )
    def whenSomethingHappens( self ):
        # doing work
        if itAllWentToHell:
            for c in self.clients:
                c.error( self, "some status object" )
        else:
            for c in self.clients:
                c.update( self, the pushed data )
    def waitFor( self ):
        # observers are waiting...
        return theData
    def status( self ):
        return self.currentState
```